# Cannot Decrease the Sequence Number of an Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

At first I thought the following error was a date/time problem, but upon further inspection it seems to be related to setting the `title` of a `CalendarEvent`:

```
[14-05-08 16:47:26:183 EDT] CalendarEvent.setTitle([HOLD: TES 101-01, Test, 10 -- Test Training (1 of 1)]) [0.067 seconds]
[14-05-08 16:47:26:189 EDT] Execution failed: Service error: CalendarApp: Cannot decrease the sequence number of an event (line 374, file "Save Changes") [1.245 seconds total runtime]
```

and line 374 of the script is the following:

```
eventToUpdate.setTitle(title);
```

The variables are fine - `eventToUpdate` (when logged) is a `CalendarEvent` object, so `setTitle(title)` should work fine. The `title` variable contains a string, as shown in the error from the Execution Transcript.

This started happening recently, without any changes to the code. I created a few functions to test title-changes, and it turns out that the error only occurs when the **time** of the event is also changed, and **only** if the time is changed *before* the title is changed. If the time is changed *after* the title is changed, there is no error. See the following code:

```
function eventTitleChangeTest() {
  var calStart = new Date("Thu May 08 17:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014");
  var calEnd = new Date("Thu May 08 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014");
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(getLibraryProperty('LRCalName'))[0];

  var event = calendar.createEvent("Temporary Title", calStart, calEnd);
  var eventID = event.getId();
  Logger.log(event.getTitle());
  changeTitleById(eventID);
  changeTitleByTime(calStart, calEnd);
}

function changeTitleById(id) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(getLibraryProperty('LRCalName'))[0];
  var event = calendar.getEventSeriesById(id);
  event.setTitle("ID-based Title Change");
  Logger.log(event.getTitle());
}

function changeTitleByTime(start, end) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(getLibraryProperty('LRCalName'))[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);
  var eventToChange = events[0];
  // The line below is the problem (it comes before the title change)
  eventToChange.setTime(new Date("Wed May 07 17:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014"), new Date("Wed May 07 17:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014"));
  eventToChange.setTitle("Time-based Title Change");
  // But if I change the time AFTER the title, it works without a problem. But why?
  //eventToChange.setTime(new Date("Wed May 07 17:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014"), new Date("Wed May 07 17:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014"));
  Logger.log(eventToChange.getTitle());
}

function deleteEvent(id) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(getLibraryProperty('LRCalName'))[0];
  calendar.getEventSeriesById(id).deleteEventSeries();
}
```

So the question is: **Why does changing the date/time of a `CalendarEvent` before changing the *title* cause this error?**

And subsequently, *is this a bug?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence number must be non-decreasing and some changes increase the sequence number, see
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.7.4

You should always modify the most recent version of the event with the current sequence number. In this case I assume the changes are immediately propagated to the server after each setter. That means you could try to re-fetch "eventToChange" after the first modification before you do the next one.

Comment: Luc, interesting idea about the sequence number - I looked in the RFC and couldn't find changes that increase or decrease the sequence number. However, I was able to find a resource that [does define](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/sequence.html) what causes a sequence number to increase. So, if the error is that the sequence number cannot be *decreased*, then I may be trying to change the sequence number of a *stale* iCal object, an old reference? I'll take a look at the code soon and let you know how it goes. Very good suggestion!

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Please let me know how it went ;)

Comment: Luc, that was indeed the answer! No longer receiving the error, thanks for the tip :)